# How to update a sequence column using single update statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, update, unique-constraint

I have a table, lets call it `foo` which consist a column `priority` and has a unique constraint on it.

lets assume below is the current state of `foo` table :-

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+-----+----------+
| id  | priority |
+-----+----------+
| 1   |        5 |
| 2   |        6 |
| 3   |        7 |
+-----+----------+
```

Now I have a requirement where,if I insert a another row with `priority` value of `6`, then it should insert this row and move `priority` of all the rows which has its value `>=` to 6 to 1 priority down.

So revised table should look like below :-

```
mysql> select * from foo;
    +-----+----------+
    | id  | priority |
    +-----+----------+
    | 1   |        5 |
    | 2   |        7 |
    | 3   |        8 |
    | 4   |        6 |
    +-----+----------+
```

I want to use a sql statement like

`update foo set priority=priority+1 where priority >=6;` But obviously it will fail with below error :-

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '7' for key 'priority'.

Is there is any other way of doing the same thing.

Comment: You should either update before insert the new value or use a [BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3ab3ba5008ea3d1520e4950a27a56242

Comment: @McNets , yeah I am doing update before insert only but my update will only fail as when I try to update priority 6 to 7, it will fail saying 7 already exist. edit in the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that can help you.

```
update foo set prio = prio+1 where prio >= 6 order by prio desc;
insert into foo (prio) values(6);
```